# Error JSON stringify format

Tags: javascript, api, calendar

```
var email_recept=document.getElementsByClassName("email");
        var counting_email_recept=email_recept.length;
        var array_mail=[];
        var myJSON=[];
        for(var i=0;i<counting_email_recept;i++)
        {
            array_mail[i]=email_recept[i].value;
            myJSON[i]=JSON.stringify({ email: array_mail[i] });         
        }

console.log(myJSON);
result :
["{"email":""}", "{"email":""}"]
i want to make like this : [{"email":""}, {"email":""}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this code:

```
var email_recept=document.getElementsByClassName("email");
var counting_email_recept=email_recept.length;
var array_mail=[];
var myJSON=new array();
for(var i=0;i<counting_email_recept;i++)
{
    array_mail[i]=email_recept[i].value;
    myjson[i] = { email: array_mail[i] };
}
myJSON = JSON.stringify(myJSON);
console.log(myJSON);
```

And you will get desired output!

Comment: yes you are right, buat when i change my jason to "attendees":myJSON, it can not read, but if i write "attendees": [{"email":"xxx@gmail.com"},{"email":"xxx@gmail.com"}] its suces

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little ambiguous, but I think you may want...

```
var myJSON=[];

for(var i=0;i<counting_email_recept;i++) {
    array_mail[i]=email_recept[i].value;
    myJSON[i]={ email: array_mail[i] };
}

myJSON = JSON.stringify(myJSON);

// '[{"email":"a@a.a"},{"email":"b@b.b"}]'
```